# appending comma as user inputs in a textfield swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an input text where user enter amount. The problem I have now is if a user enters the value `1000` I want it to show up in the text field as `1,000` and when I want to get the value of the `textField`, I want to be able to get `1000` back. how can I achieve this as codes that I have tried can only help out in printing the value in `1,000`

```
extension Formatter {
    static let withSeparator: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.groupingSeparator = ","
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension Integer{    
    var formattedWithSeparator: String {
        return Formatter.withSeparator.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

let myInt = 1234500
let myIntString = myInt.formattedWithSeparator  // "1,234,500"
```

Comment: Isn't it better to assign a number formatter component to your text field in your storyboard?

Comment: how can I do that? I checked but could get anything

Comment: Have you made sure that the user can only enter digits 0...9 (no letters, no decimal separator, no grouping separator) ? Is it set to use a numeric pad?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code u will get it

import UIKit

```
class IntegerField: UITextField {
    var lastValue = 0
    let maxValue = 1_000_000_000
    var amount: Int {
        if let newValue = Int(string.digits), newValue < maxValue {
            lastValue = newValue
        } else if !hasText {
            lastValue = 0
        }
        return lastValue
    }
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        textAlignment = .right
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        text = Formatter.decimal.string(for: amount)
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        text = Formatter.decimal.string(for: amount)
    }
}

extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}
struct Formatter {
    static let decimal = NumberFormatter(numberStyle: .decimal)
}
extension UITextField {
    var string: String { return text ?? "" }
}

extension String {
    private static var digitsPattern = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
    var digits: String {
        return unicodeScalars.filter { String.digitsPattern ~= $0 }.string
    }
}

extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == UnicodeScalar {
    var string: String { return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(self)) }
}
```

Comment: nope i have tried before he posting the url for easy clarification i have provided the code

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way :

```
extension Int {
   var intString = "\(self)"
    let lenght = intString.count

    for i in 0...lenght {
        if i % 3 == 0 && i != 0 {
            intString.insert(",", at: String.Index(encodedOffset: lenght - i))
        }
    }

    if intString.first == "," {
        intString.removeFirst()
    }

    return intString

}
```

and

```
extension String {
   func removeCommas() -> Int {

       var copy = String()

       for character in self {
           if character != "," {
               copy.append(character)
           }
       }

       if let int = Int(copy) {
           return int
       } else {
           return 0
       }
   }
}
```

then you can use those functions with your strings / int like that :

```
let string = 1435.addCommas() //Return "1,435"
let int = "1,234,567".removeCommas() //Return 1234567
```

So you can have a function called when your textField text changes in your viewController :

```
@IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {

    if textField.text != "" {
        myIntNumber = textField.text!.removeCommas()
        textField.text = myIntNumber.addCommas()
    }

}
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort to answer and helping people but the logic you have used seems wrong. Why wrong? 
if i % 3 == 0 && i != 0 {
            intString.insert(",", at: String.Index(encodedOffset: lenght - i))
            commasCount += 1
        }
After some digits the amount will be turns into this formate i.e xx,xx,xx.... so at that time the logic you have been used will get fail.

Comment: Are  you sure ? If I do print(Int.max.addCommas()), this returns 9.223.372.036.854.775.807 as expected, I tried it few times with a text field too and it works every time.

Comment: What if the amount will come in the format of not just x,xxx,xxx... but xx,xx,xx... ?